# TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns, UTC]] to [int32]

Tags: python, isolation-forest

i am trying to run this code and getting this error .m data looks like this
[image]

TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns, UTC]] to [int32]

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import seaborn as sns
    from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
    data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", parse_dates=['timestamp'])
    data['timestamp'] = data['timestamp'].astype('int')
    model=IsolationForest(n_estimators=50, max_samples='auto', contamination=float(0.1),max_features=1.0)
    model.fit(data[['timestamp','a','b','c','d','e','f','g',    'h','i','j','k']])
    data['scores']=model.decision_function(data[['timestamp','a','b','c','d','e','f','g',   'h','i','j','k']])
    data['anomaly']=model.predict(data[['timestamp','a','b','c','d','e','f','g',    'h','i','j','k']])
```

the table is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
data['timestamp'] = data['timestamp'].astype('datetime64[s]').astype('int')
```

It converts to seconds first and then to an int.